# How do you use Alternate Data Streams and what are the benefits?

Tags: winapi, alternate-data-stream

I've read some documentations about `Alternate Data Streams` and I'm thinking about using them in my own projects. However there is so much unknown knowledge and open questions that I still have before I decide to use them. That's why I made this question list:

1. How do you enum Streams without the Sysinternals tool `streams`?
2. Does a stream affect the "Host" File's MD5 Value?
3. What happens if I copy/cut the "Host" File to another (NTFS) Path? Do the streams copy/cut themselves too?
4. What happens if I copy/cut the "Host" File to another Path that is NOT NTFS?
5. Is it possible to have another Stream in an existing stream?
6. Since you will have an actual filehandle for each stream, is it possible to change a stream's attributes?
7. Can I use the `LoadLibrary` API to load a DLL from a stream?
8. Is it possible to execute (e.g. `ShellExecute`) a stream?
9. What are the advantages/benefits/disadvantages using `Alternate Data Streams`?
10. What do I have to be cautious about if I use `Alternate Data Streams`?

I'm looking forward to your answers/infos/summarys. The preferable language is Delphi but any other language will do too, as long as it uses the `WinAPI`.

Comment: Your question looks like _"I want to know everything"_. Please explain what you are actually planning to do with ADS.

Comment: I'm planning to use `ADS`. However there are open questions that are undocumented or have never been asked.

Comment: Which features are undocumented????

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many of your questions are covered here: http://flexhex.com/docs/articles/alternate-streams.phtml

1. Enumeration: Use `NtQueryInformationFile`, see link. Beginning with Windows Vista, you can also enumerate streams on the commandline using `dir /r`.
2. Checksums: As you usually open only the unnamed data stream when you access a file by name, only the contents of this stream are used when calculating checksums.
3. Copying to NTFS: Windows Explorer and the copy commandline utility copy all streams.
4. Copying to other FS: The alternate data streams are lost.
5. Nested streams: No, a file simply consists of a list of streams, they cannot be nested.
6. Attributes: Some attributes are file-based, some (encrypted, compressed, sparse) are stream-based.
7. `LoadLibrary` seems to work on alternate data streams.
8. `ShellExecute` on an ADS failed with `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` (2) on my computer.

   Note that is is theoretically possible to run an ADS from the commandline:

   `type calc.exe > dummy.txt:calc`

   `wmic process call create "dummy.txt:calc"`
9. ADS are useful to store some non-critical information associated with a file. For example, executable files downloaded from the internet will have an ADS which causes Explorer to display a warning before the file is executed.
10. See link. In particular, don't use them for critical data.

Comment: `dir /r` will list streams also if your playing @ the command line

Comment: NTFS is not the only file system that supports named streams. Contrary to what the article recommends (as safe), one should query [GetVolumeInformation()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993(v=vs.85).aspx)'s FILE_NAMED_STREAMS flag instead.